# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) while trying something out using MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

Iam trying to fetch a book's title from database and print it using MVC. I am using Visual Studio 2015, SQL Server Express 2012.
Here is the snippet of code Iam trying to run.

**Controller :**

```
{
public class BooksController : Controller
{
    // GET: Books
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Book book = new Book();
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-2TQQ3C8\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;");
        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
        }
        SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("select * from Books");
        sqlCom.Connection = sqlCon;
        SqlDataReader dr = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            book.BookName = dr[0].ToString();
        }
        return View(book);
    }
}
```

}

**Model :**

```
namespace MVC_trial1_11012016.Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string BookName { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string Overview { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate {get; set;}
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public string HardCover { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**View :**

```
    @model MVC_trial1_11012016.Models.Book
   <h2>@Model.BookName</h2>
```

When I run this in Chrome, a blank page is displayed and when i open the console it shows the following:
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW04i.png)

[Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msAsc.png)

Please tell me where I went wrong?
Sorry if this is not worth your time, but i tried to check on the interent and didn't find any answer. So please help me out. I just started learning MVC.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your if (dr.HasRows) line and check the value of dr.

Comment: Hi @kami I tried that. It seems like it is not executing upto that point. I even tried placing a break point at the 1st statement where i created a instance for the model. It didn't come to that either.

Comment: Is your link to the view set properly to use the BooksController?

Comment: Yes, I believe. I saw how to do that in a video.